# Android USB tethering to an OpenWRT router

Tags: usb, tethering

I'd like to USB-tether my Android phone to a local router. I have a tether plan, so that's not an issue.

My reasons why I want it this way:

- the router should expose the internet to all clients, not the phone
- reduced cross-chatter, no additional (second) wifi
- local connections are handled by the router, not the phone

I know there are other devices out there, like ZyXEL's routers and apps like ZoomTether.  That last one is almost like what I need — but I want a device, not a computer connected.

Has anybody done this?

Comment: BTW, the official word from ZyXEL: "Phone tethering will not work as there is no way to load the usb drivers for the phone onto the mwr222 to allow the tethering to work.."

Answer (score 6):

Use OpenWRT 10.03 or later. Install the following modules:

```
kmod-nls-base
kmod-usb2
kmod-usb-core
kmod-usb-net
kmod-usb-net-cdc-ether
kmod-usb-net-rndis
kmod-usb-ohci
kmod-usb-uhci
```

Then edit `/etc/config/network`. Under the WAN configuration, change `option ifname eth1` to `option ifname usb0`. Then enable USB tethering on the phone and reboot the router.

[This article](https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?pid=146384) has some information about how to get the configuration smoother so you don't need to reboot the router each time you want to tether. [This article](http://lgallardo.com/en/2011/05/26/usando-el-anclaje-de-red-tethering-de-android-en-openwrt/) has a simpler way.

Comment: Note that on some (all?) phones you need to manually enable USB tethering after each USB connect (or reboot). That may cause a connection loss after a blackout and you need to manually 'fix' this each time. You may want to change that behaviour via some /etc/init.d/* script (root required though) or so

Comment: Awesome, thanks David!  This will take me a while to test out - I'll let you know the results. *fingers crossed*

Comment: @end-user - how'd it go?

Comment: I wasn't able to get it to work.  Granted, I didn't convert over to OpenWRT from dd-wrt.  I assumed, perhaps wrongly, that they share a common ancestor and have access to similar modules.  I was able to find some of them, but it looks like dd-wrt uses an older-model package management system (a little surprising).  Up-shot is I don't have a lot of time to fiddle and haven't kept at it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll be sure to check out OpenWRT if / when I ever get LTE in my city. Cheers.

Comment: I think that link provided has a better package list than yours `opkg install kmod-usb-uhci kmod-usb-net-rndis kmod-usb-acm` I think you're requiring dependencies of those packages.